# What's the equivalent to `solve` for `pinv`?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

A linear system `A @ x = b` can be solved in (at least) two ways:

1. evaluate the inverse explicitly and apply it to `b`, i.e., `x = np.linalg.inv(A) @ b`.
2. use `x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)`.

The latter is usually preferred for both performance and numerical reasons. Is there an analogue to `solve` for the pseudoinverse `pinv`? In other words, I'm looking for a function `psolve` such that `psolve(A, b) == np.linalg.pinv(A) @ b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) or [`scipy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lstsq.html#scipy.linalg.lstsq).

For example, in the following, `x1` is computed using `numpy.linalg.pinv`, and `x2` is computed using `numpy.linalg.lstsq`.

```
In [251]: A = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3, 3)

In [252]: b = np.array([0, -1, 9])

In [253]: x1 = np.linalg.pinv(A) @ b

In [254]: x1
Out[254]: array([ 2.91666667,  0.5       , -1.91666667])

In [255]: x2, res, rnk, s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)

In [256]: x2
Out[256]: array([ 2.91666667,  0.5       , -1.91666667])
```

Comment: Nice! Do you know whether there is a version that supports batching akin to `pinv`? E.g., if I have a tensor `A` with shape `(n, m, m)` and tensor `b` with shape `(n, m)`, I'd like to find the solution `x` with shape `(n, m)`.

Comment: The `b` parameter can contain multiple vectors, but in your notation, the shape must be `(m, n)`, so the `b` vectors are the columns of the array. `A` must have two dimensions.  In NumPy, there has been some discussion and work towards  allowing `A` to have shape `(n, m, m)` (or more generally, `(n, m0, m1)`) and broadcasting the inputs, but such a change never made it into the public API of a release (because of API design and backwards compatibility issues, IIRC).

Comment: If you don't mind working with private functions that could change or even be removed in a future release, there are `lstsq_m` and `lstsq_n` in the private module `numpy.linalg._umath_linalg`. These undocumented functions are "gufuncs", so they will broadcast their arguments. They are used by the public function `numpy.linalg.lstsq`. The first three arguments are `A`, `b` and `rcond`, but note that `rcond` is not optional, and must be a floating point value.